# Truffle -- Microsoft JScript runtime error

Tags: truffle

Running truffle from command line gives me this Windows 7 popup message:

[image: error]

While init runs successfully. I see file truffle.js in my project folder. How can I handle this gently?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Otherwise you can simply rename the file

```
C:\User\name\AppData\Roaming\npm\truffle.bat
```

(for exmaple in `truf.bat`); in this way, as you said, avoid confusion with microsoft command lines.

**Update (12.07.2018)**

It is a known problem and now also part of the official [truffle-documentation](https://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration#resolving-naming-conflicts-on-windows). They provide 4 different solutions:

- Call the executable file explicitly using its `.cmd` extension (`truffle.cmd compile`)
- Edit the system `PATHEXT` environment variable and remove `.JS;` from the list of executable extensions
- Rename `truffle.js` to something else (`truffle-config.js`)
- Use [Windows PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/) or [Git BASH](https://git-for-windows.github.io/), as these shells do not have this conflict.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I've solved it:

```
C:\Users\steve\AppData\Roaming\npm\truffle migrate
```

looks like architecture flaw if truffle: config file is truffle.js, which confuses windows command line...

Comment: This ! 
It's truffle.js that is causing the issue. Simply delete it and use truffle-config.js only.