# What can i do if truffle doesn't execute commands?

Tags: truffle, truffle-test

[image]

First of all i can´t execute truffle writing *truffle consol*e. Instead of that I have to write *truffle.cmd console*. When im in the truffle console and I try to execute test over my contracts I get syntax error over test. I can´t solve this issue because in truffle docu the way toexecute test is that way.

Any help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're in the truffle console you shouldn't use the `truffle` keyword anymore - all commands go to truffle directly.

The problem with executing `truffle` in Windows is a known one and looks like it hasn't been fixed yet ([Truffle -- Microsoft JScript runtime error](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/21017/truffle-microsoft-jscript-runtime-error)). Just use `truffle.cmd` instead of `truffle` and all will work just fine.

Comment: Thx for the clear answer. I hope will help more people in future

Answer (score 0):

I solve the issue writing only test. Without truffle in the command line